# string encoded with AntiXssEncoder does not return correct value for Contains "&#10;"

Tags: c#, html-encode, antixsslibrary

I have a string that was encoded with AntiXssEncoder

**"Some text,\r\n\r&#1​0;Another text .\r\n\r\nThird text "**

I want to replace `&#1​0;` with `<br/>` or `\n` for new line, but when I check if string contains

`"&#1​0;"` result in false,

Also Replace("`&#1​0;`","`<br/>`") does not replace anything

[image]

Comment: `Replace("&#1​0;","<br/>") ` not seeming to replace anything can just mean one of two things: Either there is no `"&#1​0;" in your string, or you simply don't use or otherwise ignore/forget the string with the replacements returned by Replace (i assume you referred to string.Replace). It's up to you to figure out which of those two possibilities is the actual reason for your problem. (Well, there is also a 3rd possibility in that you somewhere during troubleshooting made a mistake and started chasing a red herring; in which case your question wouldn't represent the actual problem in your code)

Comment: "when I check if string contains" how do you perform the check? Where's your (failing) code?

Comment: Please copy & paste code in to the question, rather than using images of code.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your code (something to read: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2819245), [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)). Instead, add the code as **code-formatted** text to your question...

Comment: With regard to your problem: Dump your htmlToEncode string into a char array (or a text file). Then look into the char array (or use a hex editor to look at the byte content of the file) and analyze the chars at the positions that make up `&#10;`. It very much looks like there are some some non-printable (invisible) control characters or other invisible/zero-width UTF-16 code points  somewhere between the characters making up `&#10;`, thus making the string.Contains and string.Replace methods not detect a 'pure' `&#10;`...

Comment: Also note that there are at least 2 similar ampersand characters (each with separate character codes, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampersand#Encoding_and_display). When analyzing the chars in the char array (or in the file), pay attention to the actual ordinal (numeric) character code values. It might be that your sample string might contain an `&` (or other character) which is not using the common char code but one of possible alternative char codes. Depending on the actual font used to display such characters, the character shape itself might _not_ reveal a different underlying char code

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, you're not just throwing the generated string away returned by .Replace()?

This should work:

```
        var foo = "Some text,\r\n\r&#1​0;Another text .\r\n\r\nThird text";
        System.Console.WriteLine(foo); //Output: Some text,\r\n\r&#1​0;Another text .\r\n\r\nThird text
        System.Console.WriteLine(foo.Contains("&#1​0;")); //Output: True

        var bar = foo.Replace("&#1​0;", "<br/>");
        System.Console.WriteLine(bar); // Output: Output: Some text,\r\n\r<br/>Another text .\r\n\r\nThird text
```